# How do I output a list of a specific post type in a table?

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I've used the [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/) plugin to create a new post type of "Job". It includes a couple custom fields for "Location" and "Job Type".

I have a page called "Jobs", and now I'd like to display a table on the Jobs page that shows an HTML table, with eg:

```
Job Title              Location       Type
Web Developer          Canada         Full-time 
Data Entry             USA            Contract
Sales Rep              Switzerland    Full-time
```

and obviously clickable links to view the job page.

I know I can do this by creating a custom template and writing the code, but it seems to me like this is a pretty straight-forward thing, so I was kind of expecting there would be a shortcode or something that I could use to easily display this.

Is there a way to do this? A plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. If the plugin doesn't provide a shortcode, then simply "No". Templates are considered to be easy, so this is the way to go.